# Updating an array based on randomly generated index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random, html-lists

I'm very new to Javascript and jQuery. I'm trying to create a film list that will randomly pick an item from the list, post the result, and remove the item from the original list. It uses text input, .push and .append to keep track of the list and update an array of matching text. My thinking was that I would use an array that matches the ul to generate a random index number from its length and then use the number to remove the li from the ul by index. The basic idea is working. My issue is that every time it selects an item from the list, the item it removes from the array is different than the item it posts and removes from the ul. The parts seem to work fine separately until I run them in a function together tied to a button.

Here is the code I'm using. The watchList array is populated with a .push whenever text is accepted to update the ul. I've checked and the index for both match up.

```
function randomShow(){
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * watchList.length);
for(var i = 0; i < watchList.length; i++){
    if(i === r) {
            alert(watchList[i]);
            watchList.splice(watchList.indexOf[i],1);
            $("li").eq(i).remove();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `watchList.indexOf(i)` and you can get rid of the loop in your code, it's pointless.

Comment: Yes. I figured out the loop was useless. Someone else suggested I try it and since I'm really new to coding I gave it a shot. I fixed it. Your suggestion was close but definitely pointed me in the right direction! I removed the loop and remove the indexOf altogether. - watchList.splice(r,1); -

Answer (score 0):

I think you don’t need a loop. Try this;

```
function randomShow(){
   var r = Math.floor(Math.random() *watchList.length);
   $("li").eq(r).remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before trying the loop. Both of them get the same result.  Right now it removes and posts the correct item from the list but removes the wrong item from the array when it runs the splice, which renders it useless after one use. I feel like maybe it's running a separate instance of r every time r is called instead of passing the same instance to both. Is there a way to pull an index based on the length of the list while also printing the text content of that index?